# dbus c api example doesn't work

Tags: c, ubuntu-12.04, dbus

I work on UBuntu 12.04 LTS. I'm trying to use sendsignal and receive functions from this [site](http://www.matthew.ath.cx/misc/dbus) but they don't work correctly. In my program I first call sendsignal("mySignal) then receive(). I get following info:

```
Sending signal with value mySignal
Name Error(Connection ":1.95" is not allowed to own the service "test.signal.source" due to security policies in the configuration file)
```

Because of that I replaced `conn = dbus_bus_get(DBUS_BUS_SYSTEM, &err);` with  `conn = dbus_bus_get(DBUS_BUS_SESSION, &err);` in both functions. Now a signal is sent but receive function doesn't see that signal, i.e. NULL == msg that's true. I also commented out `dbus_connection_close(conn);` because of the following error:

```
process 12612: Applications must not close shared connections - see dbus_connection_close() docs. This is a bug in the application.
```

How to make it working ?

Comment: Still need help? It would be better if you tried to describe what you are fundamentally trying to achieve. Also, if you get permissions problems, try running the program as root.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try:

- Run `dbus-launch` in a terminal. Copy and paste the terminal output to a file, and edit it to export the content as environment variables. By doing this, you launch a new dbus daemon  and exposes it to the subsequent application.
- Source the environment setting file in your terminal before running both the signal sending and receiving examples. This makes the app connects to the new session bus.

I'm guessing your sending example is launching its own dbus daemon, but the other app does not have a clue what the daemon is, thus you need to expose the daemon through an env variable. Another possible cause is your sending and receiving application are using the defaule login session bus but the policy does not allow them to use.

Let us know if this works or not.